# Using Real-ESRGAN Onnx in Flutter

Tags: python, flutter, machine-learning, deep-learning, onnx

How can I implement Real-ESRGAN ONNX in flutter. I'm not professional at this.
Someone can help providing example inference code. I've converted the model from pytorch to onnx.

I've tried with some example data and worked, but don't know to do further more

```
` OrtSession? _session;
  String? progress;
  String? infstatus;
  Uint8List? enhanced;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    progress = "Initializing ONNX Runtime...";
    print('Initializing ONNX Runtime...');
    _initializeOrt();
    progress = "Creating ONNX session...";
    print('Creating ONNX session...');
    _createSession();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeOrt() async {
    try {
      await OrtEnv.instance.init();
      setState(() {
        progress = "ONNX Runtime initialized successfully.";
      });
      _createSession();
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        progress = 'Error initializing ONNX Runtime: $e';
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _createSession() async {
    try {
      final sessionOptions = OrtSessionOptions();
      const assetFileName = 'assets/RealESRGAN_x4plus_anime_6B.onnx';
      final rawAssetFile = await rootBundle.load(assetFileName);
      final bytes = rawAssetFile.buffer.asUint8List();
      _session = OrtSession.fromBuffer(bytes, sessionOptions);
      print('ONNX session created successfully.');
      setState(() {
        progress = "ONNX session created successfully.";
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        progress = "Error creating ONNX session: $e";
      });
      print('Error creating ONNX session: $e');
    }
  }
  Future<void> _runInference() async {
    print('Running inference...');
    setState(() {
      infstatus = "Running inference...";
    });

    final shape = [1, 3, 100, 100];
    var data = Float32List.fromList(
        List.filled(1 * 3 * 100 * 100, 0.5)); // Sample data using Float32List
    final inputOrt = OrtValueTensor.createTensorWithDataList(data, shape);
    final inputs = {'input': inputOrt};
    final runOptions = OrtRunOptions();
    List<OrtValue?>? outputs;

    try {
      outputs = await _session?.runAsync(runOptions, inputs);
      print('Inference result: ${outputs?[0]}'); // Handle your output here
      setState(() {
        infstatus = "Inference result: ${outputs?[0]}";
      });

    } catch (e) {
      print('Error during inference: $e');
    } finally {
      inputOrt.release();
      runOptions.release();
      outputs?.forEach((element) {
        element?.release();
      });
    }
```

}

Library:
Onnx: https://github.com/gtbluesky/onnxruntime_flutter

The example usage in python :

```
`import cv2
import numpy as np
import onnxruntime as rt
import torch
import time

# Load the ONNX model with CUDA execution provider
sess = rt.InferenceSession('RealESRGAN_x4plus_anime_6B.onnx')
print("loaded model.")

# Load the input image
in_image = cv2.imread('input.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
print("loaded input image.")

# Convert BGR to RGB and transpose dimensions
in_mat = cv2.cvtColor(in_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
in_mat = np.transpose(in_mat, (2, 1, 0))[np.newaxis]
in_mat = in_mat.astype(np.float32)
in_mat = in_mat / 255

# Start time for measuring inference time
start_time = time.time()

# Get input and output names
input_name = sess.get_inputs()[0].name
output_name = sess.get_outputs()[0].name

print("Input name: ", input_name)
print("Output name: ", output_name)


# Convert input to torch tensor and move it to GPU
in_mat = torch.tensor(in_mat)

# Run inference
out_mat = sess.run([output_name], {input_name: in_mat.cpu().numpy()})[0]


# Measure and print elapsed time
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print('Inference time: ',elapsed_time)
# Save the output image
out_mat = (out_mat.squeeze().transpose((2, 1, 0)) * 255).clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite('outpust.jpg', out_mat)
print("Output image saved.")`
```